# How to copy/access file in Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

Working on Spring boot microservice and we have file in the folder file/Service.wsdl

And we are accessing the file using

```
@Value("file:file/Service.wsdl")  
String WSDL_LOCATION;
```

In Kubernetes, we are getting "file/directory not found"...How to solve this.

Comment: Is log enabled? Is that file readable?

Comment: Yes, locally it is working, on the K8s facing issue

Comment: Can you access the file via `kubectl` cmds?

Comment: How to use kubectl command, as I am new to DevOps

Comment: Here is the guide... https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/

Comment: Please provide a bit more of your code, the whole Class maybe or how you defined `WSDL_LOCATION`? And what is the whole path to your file? It can't be just `file/Service.wsdl`.

Comment: able to make it work,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this @Value("${file:file/Service.wsdl}")
String WSDL_LOCATION;

Or else you can create config map of using this file and use that path .